# How to create template for class that manages array of structs

Tags: c++, templates, arduino

I want to create a reusable class that describes an array of structs which contain a pointer to a method in a class. The class also contains "execute" and "show" methods. I think the execute method needs to be templated as well, but I am still struggling to learn templates.

CHALLENGE: How do I turn this class into a template and provide a
couple examples of using the template?

This class combines `typedef`, `struct` and methods that I want to share across multiple classes. Each instance will have its own array of `struct`, each of which contains a pointer to a string and a pointer to a method in a class.

I want to use templates so it supports multiple instances of arrays of this same `struct`, but the contents are different.

What this code represents is a method of implementing a simple command language that passes the two codes (sel and act) to an execute method which searches the array for a match on the two codes and then dispatches the corresponding method.

This code also includes two methods that also need to be included in the template: `show` (walks the array and provides help info for each command) and `execute` which calls the appropriate function.

```
class Commands {
public:
    typedef void ( Commands::*FunctionPointer )( char, char );


    struct command {
        char sel;
        char act;
        char const *desc;
        FunctionPointer funcPtr;
    };


    command myCommands [2] = {
        command { 'a','?',"Pass a and ? to foo", &Commands::foo },
        command { 'b','x',"Pass b and x to bar", &Commands::bar },
    };


    int cmdSize = sizeof ( myCommands ) / sizeof ( myCommands [0] );


    void foo ( char sel, char act ) {
        show ( { sel }, { act } );
    }


    void bar ( char sel, char act ) {
        show ( { sel }, { act } );
    }


    void show ( char sel, char act ) {
        //  sel and act are ignored vy this method
        for (int i = 0; i < cmdSize; i++) {
            Serial.print ( "SEL = " );
            Serial.print ( myCommands [i].sel );
            if (sel == myCommands [i].sel) Serial.print ( '*' );
            Serial.print ( ", ACT=" );
            Serial.print ( myCommands [i].act );
            if (act == myCommands [i].act) Serial.print ( '*' );
            Serial.print ( ' ' );
            Serial.println ( myCommands [i].desc );
        }
    }


    void execute ( char sel, char act ) {
        for (int i = 0; i < cmdSize; i++) {
            if (myCommands [i].sel == sel && myCommands [i].act == act) {
                Serial.println ( myCommands [i].desc );
                ( this->*myCommands [i].funcPtr )( sel, act );
                return;
            }
        }
        Serial.print ( F ( "Unknown SEL/ACT Pair:" ) );
        Serial.print ( sel );
        Serial.print ( '/' );
        Serial.println ( act );
    }
};
```

And the Arduino Sketch:

```
#include "Commands.h"

Commands cmd;


void setup() {
    Serial.begin ( 115200 );
    cmd.show ( '?', '?' );
    Serial.println ( "EXECUTING:" );
    cmd.execute ( 'a', '?' );
    cmd.execute ( 'b', '?' );
    cmd.execute ( 'b', 'x' );
    Serial.println ( "DONE" );
}


void loop(){}
```

And finally, the output of executing the sketch:

```
SEL = a, ACT=?* Pass a and ? to foo
SEL = b, ACT=x Pass b and x to bar
EXECUTING:
Pass a and ? to foo
SEL = a*, ACT=?* Pass a and ? to foo
SEL = b, ACT=x Pass b and x to bar
Unknown SEL/ACT Pair:b/?
Pass b and x to bar
SEL = a, ACT=? Pass a and ? to foo
SEL = b*, ACT=x* Pass b and x to bar
DONE
```

Comment: unclear what this means: `I want to templatize this code so it supports multiple instances of arrays of this same struct, but the contents are different.` please provide at least two similar classes to explain how they differ

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create a reusable class that describes an array of structs
>   which contain a pointer to a method in a class. The class also
>   contains "execute" and "show" methods. I think the execute method
>   needs to be templated as well, but I am still struggling to learn
>   templates.

I have to say that I dont understand what you want to do exactly. However, looking at your code it seems you want a `std::map`, rather than an array (so you can map "commands" to the function pointers). If all methods you want to call have the same signature (`void(char,char)`) then you dont need to deal much with templates. Instead I'd suggest you to take a look at [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and lambdas.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
struct command_center {
    using command = std::string;
    using comment = std::string;    
    using action = std::function< void(char,char) >;
    std::map< command,action > action_commands;
    void register_action_command( command c, action a) { 
        action_commands[c] = a; 
    }
    void execute( command c, char a,char b) { 
        auto it = action_commands.find(c);
        if (it == action_commands.end()) {
            std::cout << "command not found: " << c << "\n";
            return;
        }
        it->second(a,b);
    }
};

struct foo{
    void bar(char a,char b) { std::cout << a << b << " foo\n";}
};

int main(){
    command_center cc;
    cc.register_action_command("test1",[](char a,char b){ std::cout << a << b << "\n";});
    cc.execute("test1",'a','b');
    cc.execute("unknown",'a','b');
    foo f;
    cc.register_action_command("foobar",[&f](char a,char b){ f.bar(a,b); });
    cc.execute("foobar",'a','b');
}
```

Output:

```
ab
command not found: unknown
ab foo
```

Note that it could work without lamdbas and without `std::function` when you restrict yourself to a fixed signature, ie function pointers of type

```
using my_function_pointer_type = void(*)(char,char);
```

However, by passing a lambda to `std::function` you can wrap any callable with the right signature and register it to be called later (no matter if it is a free function or some member method as in the example).

PS: It is possible to parametrize the above `command_center` to work with function pointers of different signature. Only after writing this answer I realized that maybe this is what the question is about, is it?